# MvvmCross 6.2.0 top current activity

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

After updating to MvvmCross 6.2.0 my app shows the same activity several times

[TRACE] (MvxAndroid) Activity host with ViewModelType MainViewModel is not CurrentTopActivity. Showing Activity before showing Fragment for HomeViewModel

MainViewModel is the activity with a HomeViewModel Fragment

Any ideas ?
Thx

Comment: Unclear what is going on from your description. When does it show the Activity multiple times? How and where are you navigating to it?

Comment: The activity is showed right after the user log in, it happens only when the user uses the app the firest time

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example in the form of a git repo? or just share your code